# Ruby version on Netlify

Tags: ruby, rubygems, version, jekyll, netlify

I'm having some issues with Netlify.
I created a new website using Jekyll and I have my repository on Bitbucket and everything works.

I set the deploy from Bitbucket on my Netlify account but when I try to deploy it always fails and I get this error in the log:

```
9:59:15 AM: ruby_dep-1.5.0 requires ruby version >= 2.2.5, which is incompatible with the
9:59:15 AM: current version, ruby 2.1.2p95
9:59:15 AM: Error during gem install
9:59:15 AM: Build complete: exit code: 1
9:59:15 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
9:59:15 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
9:59:15 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
9:59:15 AM: Finished processing build request in 11.891885136s
```

I'm currently using this version of ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin17] and I've already generated and committed a ***.rubyversion*** file:

```
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

I can't understand what the problem could be. Could please someone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

As you can see in [netlify doc](https://www.netlify.com/docs/build-settings/#build-environment-variables) ruby version file name is ***/.ruby-version***.

In your case, you can try `2.4.2`, which is the highest supported version today.

Comment: This week Netlify will roll out support for any published major ruby version (x.y.z) up to 2.4.3 (rvm's 2.5.0 support is not quite there yet).

Answer (score 0):

You should also use a an included ruby version, otherwise this will slow down the build.

**Included Netlify Ruby versions as of November 2019 are:**

- 2.3.6
- 2.5.4
- 2.4.5
- 2.4.3
- 2.2.9
- 2.6.2

Comment: What's the source of this list? It'd be good to link to where in their docs they list the supported versions, so that we can see what the supported versions are _today_.

Comment: According to [this page](https://github.com/netlify/build-image/blob/85f74bd415e22878bad5783a3813dabcb1ffded2/included_software.md#languages), you can use "any version that rvm can install" @ivanreese. That's the only thing I could find, it doesn't seem to be in the Netlify docs. Not sure if that "2.6.2 (default)" is correct, as my builds use 2.3.6  Maybe because it's an old site?

Comment: Further note: setting it to `2.6` works, but gives this warning in the build log: `Using custom ruby version 2.6, this will slow down the build. To ensure fast builds, set the RUBY_VERSION environment variable, or .ruby-version file, to an included ruby version. Included versions: 2.5.4 2.2.9 2.4.3 2.6.2 2.4.5 2.3.6`

Comment: It seems they are removing "Included versions" like gangbusters and not documenting or issuing notice, at least that I can find. Right now Included versions listed for the Ubuntu 16.04 image is: `2.7.1`. End of list. What gives? The Ubuntu 14.04 image may offer older versions. This April 2020 article recommends Ruby 2.6.3, which is on none of these lists. When I use that version, I get the "will slow down the build" warning.